# How to prevent request via curl in my mvc4 Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I want to prevent request that comes from **curl** command in my Application.can we prevent **curl** command request ?

Answer (score 1):

cURL does nothing more than sends HTTP request to your server.
Anyone can send the exact request you send from a browser via cURL, Postman or any other tool.

However, if the person who forms the request in cURL is not so carefull, he might skip User-Agent or any other header which browser sends by default, and in this way you can distinguish non-browser requests.